# Python Hangman game - functions and variables

Tags: python, function, command-line, variable-assignment

a typical command line Hangman game here.  I'm new to Python and I'm not yet entirely comfortable with passing functions and using their results as variables.  I'm at the opening stages where the game loads with a title, introduction, displays the Hangman frame and has input validation.  The issues begin when I retrieve a random musician from a list, then try to call and display this.  I've also encountered the request for letter input duplicating.

Through trial and error, I've managed to display the musician name on the game screen (not with code as below).  However, when I try to incorporate this into the while loop in the run_game(), I run into issues with musician undefined, or the game generating a new musician after a letter being entered.  I really need a pointer in how I should be structuring these functions, calling them and using their results in variables - thanks!

Relevant code below.

```
def musician_blanks():
    """
    Retrieves random musician name from list and replaces letters with blanks
    on the game screen
    """
    musician = random.choice(musicians_list).upper()
    return musician


def letter_validation():
    while True:
        try:
            letter_input = input("Please enter a letter: \n").upper()
            if len(letter_input) == 1 and letter_input.isalpha():
                return letter_input.upper()
            else:
                print("Invalid - please enter a letter.\n")
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter one letter.\n")
    return letter_input


tries = 6


def run_game(musician):
    letter = letter_validation()
    list_musician = list(musician_blanks())
    while len(musician) > 0:
        if letter in musician:
            print("correct")
        else:
            print("incorrect")

def main():
    game_title()
    print(display_dj(tries))
    musician_blanks()
    musician = musician_blanks()
    run_game(musician)


main()
```

Comment: can we see this function `display_dj(tries)`?

Comment: It only shows the stages of the hangman character…

Comment: Every time you call `musician_blanks()` is picks a different musician. So `list_musician` is a different musician from `musician`.

Comment: But you never use the variable `list_musician`, what is it for?

Comment: Nothing in your `try` can raise `ValueError`, so the `except` will never be used.

Comment: You should be printing the hangman character inside the `run_game()` loop, not in the caller.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. The list_musician is for the loop to iterate through to check if the letter is in the word.  I know that code doesn’t show it being called as I’ve tried it in the loop and it hasn’t worked. Any suggestions? The intention is to show the hangman inside the run game once I get the other functions working. I just started the code that way to get it displaying at start.

Comment: But `list_musician` is a different word. Use `list_musician = list(musician)`, don't call `musician_blanks()` again.